# Possible to get question/answer data for previewing question?

Tags: support, api

So I know it isn't possible to make GET requests to a SO page and pull back data. I also know the API only returns question/answer IDs and urls, which is not what I am looking for.

What I am looking for is a way to offer users a preview of a stackoverflow question, from an external site, using only the URL to the question.

Is this possible without going through a proxy website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the whole body of a question or answer through the API. For example, [here is your question retrieved through the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/272869?order=desc&sort=activity&site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=!9YdnSJBlX). You just need to adjust the filter so that it includes the `body` field.

For more, see [API docs](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Comment: This brings me to another good point - I have looked at the API docs before, and I am looking just now, and it is not clear that this is possible. Am I being dense? Is it then possible to return the body of an answer to a question, for example the accepted answer, in the same way?

Comment: Oh I see, the filter options really aren't obvious at all. But it looks a lot more powerful than I thought, this is great thanks!

Comment: Yes, by playing with filters you can grab answer IDs, including accepted status, etc. It takes time to learn, but it indeed powerful. The official SE mobile apps use this API to retrieve posts. Generally, [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) is the place to ask about API.